# Blackberry Custom Phone lock Screen

Tags: blackberry, locking, screen

I'm developing an application which has a unique feature. Whenever the user locks the phone, a screen is pushed above the lock screen which has an emergency button on it. Whenever user presses that button, the user is taken to another screen of my application which has few emergency numbers on which he can make a call. The user has no access to any of the functions of the phone or application other than calling on these numbers (same as a locked phone). 
My problem is how can I achieve this feature. What could be the possible ways of doing this?

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks,
Rupesh

Answer (score 3):

You will need request, and be granted the [ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_DISPLAY_LOCKED](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissions.html#PERMISSION_DISPLAY_LOCKED) permission. See the API documentation for [ApplicationPermissionsManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/applicationcontrol/ApplicationPermissionsManager.html).